# Javafx - Draw arbitrary shapes using animation

Tags: animation, javafx-8

Is there any way to draw a shape dynamically so that it appears to be drawn at runtime. Something like the following.

[image]

Comment: Are you just wanting a straight line?

Comment: @James_D Yes.. But the line can be at any angle and can go in either directions(forward or backwards).

Comment: Just use a `Line` and animate the end point with a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). There is not much to it; try and post a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @James_D I'm able to get  the required line. Thanks for the tip. What about other shapes.. like the one shown.. Is that possible to make using javafx? I'll modify my question for that.